# iTunes keeps restoring deleted playlists

Tags: itunes

Since I use iTunes Match, every few days iTunes restores some of my old playlists that I previously deleted. I think these are only the default playlists that iTunes comes with (Classical music, Music videos, Recently added, ...) but I'm not totally sure. At the same time, the "iTunes Match" link reappears in my sidebar, even though I can't do anything with it.

What triggers the reappearence of my old playlists? How can I prevent it and get rid of these playlists forever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Store -> "Update iTunes Match" to make sure the changes are synchronized.

Comment: Even though the "iTunes Match" entry keeps reappearing in my sidebar, at least the playlists seem to have gone. I don't know why iTunes doesn't sync them automatically as it does with everything else.

Comment: I was having the same problem, and this seems to be working for me. I don't know why I'd not thought to just delete the playlists and select "Update iTunes Match" to force-push the change.